# How can we get mini-batch time from Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

In the Spark streaming, there is forEachRDD with time parameter, where it is possible to take that time and use it for different purposes - metadata, create additional time column in rdd, ...

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...)
stream.foreachRDD { (rdd, time) => 
  // update metadata with time 
  // convert rdd to df and add time column
  // write df
 }
```

In Structured Streaming the API

```
val df: Dataset[Row] = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .load()

df.writeStream.trigger(...)
  .outputMode(...)
  .start()
```

How is that possible to get similar **time** (mini-batch time) data for structured streaming to be able to use it in the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have searched for a function which offers the possibility to get the batchTime but it doesn't seem to exist yet in the Spark Structured Streaming APIs.

Here's a workaround I used to get the batch time (Let's suppose that the batch interval is 2000 milliseconds) using the `foreachBatch`which allow us to get the batchId :

```
val now = java.time.Instant.now
val batchInterval = 2000
df.writeStream.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(batchInterval))
  .foreachBatch({ (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
     println(now.plusMillis(batchId * batchInterval.milliseconds))
  })
  .outputMode(...)
  .start()
```

Here's the output :

`2019-07-29T17:13:19.880Z
2019-07-29T17:13:21.880Z
2019-07-29T17:13:23.880Z
2019-07-29T17:13:25.880Z
2019-07-29T17:13:27.880Z
2019-07-29T17:13:29.880Z
2019-07-29T17:13:31.880Z
2019-07-29T17:13:33.880Z
2019-07-29T17:13:35.880Z`

I hope it helps !

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a lot!